# Reset DropdownButtonFormField value

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a DropdownButtonFormField in the app.The DropdownButtonFormField gets stored value from firestore that the user selects before.

The problem is that when user wants to select another value,the DropdownButtonFormField doesn't change to the new selected value and it shows the stored value.

I tried to reset form using `_dropdownformkey.currentState.reset()`    but nothing changed

I tried to make value to null  `onChanged` parameter,but nothing changed

How can I allow the user to select another value from the dropdown menu other than stored value?

```
 StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                    stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userx).snapshots(),
                    builder: ( context, snapshot) {
                      if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting){
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }else {

                        if(snapshot.hasData){
                          var doc_data=snapshot.data;
                          var job_title=doc_data['job_title'];

                          if(job_title != "0"){
                            jobtitle_val=job_title;
                          }else{
                            jobtitle_val=jobtitle_val;
                          }

                        }

                        return DropdownButtonFormField(
                          key: _dropdownformkey,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(30.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                              filled: true,
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
                              hintText: "Job title",
                              fillColor: Colors.grey[200]),
                          value: jobtitle_val,

                          onChanged: (String Value) {
                            jobtitle_val=null;
                            setState(() 
                              jobtitle_val = Value;
                            });
                          },
                          validator: (value) => value == null ? 'field required' : null,
                          items: jobtitle
                              .map((cityTitle) => DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: cityTitle, child: Text("$cityTitle")))
                              .toList(),
                        );

                      }
                    }
                )
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this all you need is assign null to variable and call inside `setState`

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

    void main() async {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }

    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(),
          darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
          home: const HomePage(),
        );
      }
    }

    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
    }

    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      var jobtitle_val;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      jobtitle_val = null;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text('Reset')),
              DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    filled: true,
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
                    hintText: "Job title",
                    fillColor: Colors.grey[200]),
                value: jobtitle_val,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    jobtitle_val = value;
                  });
                },
                validator: (value) => value == null ? 'field required' : null,
                items: List.generate(
                    4,
                    (index) =>
                        DropdownMenuItem(value: index, child: Text("$index"))),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```